# Using windows forms alongside wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Me and a friend are working on a relatively big project, which is basically a darts scoreboard and tournament scheme software with stats tracking etc. The problem is that the tournament scheme part has been done in Windows forms, and that is a very massive part of the project, but the scoreboard part has to be done in WPF because that UI needs a little style tweaking. The thing is how do I go about getting these 2 working in conjunction, starting the whole thing from... well the WinForms end, and it exchanging data with the Scoreboard(WPF app) I need very basic things, like passing a string from a label in the form to somewhere in the WPF window. I would move the tournaments scheme to WPF, but we just don't have enough time at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use controls created in WPF application in your Windows Forms application, for an example see [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx).

Or you can use control created in Windows Forms application in your WPF application, example:

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```